# Create regular expression dynamically with regex chars

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Say I want to match any of these files:

```
/foo/bar/baz/x
/foo/bar/baz/y/z
```

so I create a regex like so:

```
new RegExp('^/foo/bar/baz/.*')
```

however my question is - how do I tell the RegExp constructor to view `.` `*` and `^` as regular expression characters, not literal characters?

Comment: What do you mean? You have a pattern defined as a string literal and it is passed to the `RegExp` constructor. What else do you want?

Comment: Right but will the `^` and `.` and `*` characters be interpreted as literal matches or as special regex characters?

Comment: I assume they are interpreted as literals

Comment: Did you escape them? No. Why do you think they are interpreted as literal chars then?

Comment: Ok so you have to escape them to make them literals, ok, if you want to add that as an answer I will upvote

Comment: It was hard for me to get an answer to that

Comment: I did try it out, I am just stupid

Answer (score 1):

As this is node.js related, my solution would be to use quotemeta
https://github.com/substack/quotemeta

as if it was perl related my solution would be to use \Q \E ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
new RegExp('^/foo/bar/baz/.*')
```

...and

```
/^\/foo\/bar\/baz\/.*/
```

...are equivalent. Everything in the `new RegExp` string are treated as regular expression characters, not literal characters (luckily `/` does not need to be escaped).

If you *do* want to make something a literal character using the constructor syntax, make sure you use a double backslash since `\` within a string literal has its own meaning. For example, if you want to capture a literal `.` character, this:

```
new RegExp('\.')
```

...won't work right because that is interpreted the same as `'.'`, making the RegExp the same as `/./`. You'd need to do this instead:

```
new RegExp('\\.')
```

Comment: thanks, but I didn't quite follow regarding the double backslash

Comment: Added example, @AlexanderMills